# Errors trying to execute db.openrecordset in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access program created in MS 2010 using MS 2016, both 32 bit.  I get errors when trying to execute the following lines.

```
Open CurrentProject.Path & "\RGS_Isolation_Import.log" For Output As logFile
```

> error 52 Bad filename

the open statement does create the empty file

```
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM IOP_FSP_RGS_Refresh_Add_New_Cnt_qry " & _
     "ORDER BY [SW NAME (Fault_Id_T)]", dbOpenDynaset)
```

> error 3436 Failure creating file

I have confirmed the read/write settings on the PC (Windows 7), and that the db is set correctly.   This program hasn't been executed in about 6 years, but worked fine then.

Comment: Just checking, but by `confirmed the read/write settings` did you create a new txt file in the folder manually or just looked at the permissions?

Comment: permissions, but the open statement actually created the file.

Comment: All documentation that I can find utilizes `#(number)` schemes for `OPEN` statements.  Update your `As logFile` to `As #1` and see if the error persists.  May need to update any references to `logFile` to #1.

Comment: @Mike don't hard-code file handles, but make sure it says `logFile = FreeFile` somewhere. Actually IIRC the `#` needs to remain in place - try `As #logFile`

Comment: Ok.  I got the open file to work, but still have the openrecordset problem.